# How to properly pronounce ‚ür‘?

Tags: pronunciation, umlaut

I‘ve been struggling with ö and ü but after practice I can eventually pronounce them. But I find myself unable to identify that ‚ü‘ sound in words such as ‚Bürger‘ ‚Mitbürger’ and sometimes even ‚für‘. What I hear is a sound similar to ‚ur‘ as in ‚Natur‘, but not exactly the same.

So is it accents or ‚ür‘ pronounced differently from ‚ü—r‘?

P.S. My question might seem a little hard to understand but I hope you get it. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pronunciation of "Ü"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33223/pronunciation-of-%c3%9c), https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/pronunciation-of-short-german-%c3%bc, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25423/cant-find-the-difference-between-o-%c3%b6-u-und-%c3%bc, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44804/how-to-remember-umlauts-%c3%b6-and-%c3%bc, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15606/how-to-learn-explain-to-pronounce-%c3%84-%c3%96-%c3%9c-z-ch,

Comment: Do you realize *r* often is a vowel in German? It is in all your examples.